# Number comparison in C is giving incorrect result

Tags: c

I have written a program to check for Palindrome number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
    main()
    {
        int n,i;
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        /* Function Prototypes */
        int reverse(int *p);
        i=reverse(&n);
        printf("Number returned %d",i);
        if (i == n) 
        {
            printf("The number is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The number is NOT a palindrome");
        }

    }
    int reverse( int *p)
    {
        int rev=0;
        while(*p !=0)
        {
            rev=rev*10;
            rev=rev+ *p%10;
            *p=*p/10;
        }
        return (rev);
    }
```

But it's always showing "Number is not a palindrome " irrespective of number is not a palindrome or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `reverse` function leaves its argument pointing to zero. The argument doesn't need to be a pointer, and passing `n` by value instead solves the problem.

Here's fixed code, somewhat reformatted and with error-checking added.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse(int p) {
    int rev = 0;
    while (p != 0) {
        rev = rev * 10;
        rev = rev + p%10;
        p = p/10;
    }
    return rev;
}

int main(void) {
    int n, i;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("failed to read number.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    i = reverse(n);
    if (i == n) {
        printf("%d is a palindrome: reversing it gives %d\n", n, i);
    } else {
        printf("%d isn't a palindrome: reversing it gives %d\n", n, i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's an important skill to be able to debug programs. Here's a good link for some beginner techniques: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: A couple of minor improvements: (1) check that `scanf()` returned 1; (2) it is a good idea to print the input value as well as the output value —`printf("The number %d is a palindrome (reversed: %d)\n", n, i);` and `printf("The number %d is not a palindrome because it is %d when reversed\n", n, i);` as an example.  Echoing inputs, in particular, helps spot that the input number has been destroyed by the original version of `reverse()` (the one in the question).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, I included your suggestions in the code.

Comment: Thanks for making the changes.  I can't give a second up-vote — sorry.

Comment: @Anonymous  Thanks for the answer. But I still dont get it when you said "The reverse function leaves its argument pointing to zero", As you can see I had printed the value of the number after getting it from reverse function.  It had successfully reversed the number. Why I am not getting result when comparing? I could have done it with passing value but I am learning C and would wanted to do it with Pointer.

Comment: @AsfakulIslam you're passing `n` as a pointer in `reverse(&n)` and the body of `reverse` updates `*p` which is `n` in your main function. Thus you lose the original value of `n` that you read in. If you follow the advice of Jonathan and print `n` after the call to `reverse` then you can see that it's been changed to 0.

Comment: @Anonymous  Yesss! Now I get it.. Thanks a lot.